# How to get ExtJs 4 panel to update itself on data refresh

Tags: extjs

I'm using ExtJs 4.

I have a panel that looks something like this:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    title: 'Current Transaction Data',
    width: 500,
    items:[
           {
               id: 'field1',
               xtype: 'textfield',
               label:'Field 1',
           },
           {
               id: 'field 2',
               xtype: 'textfield',
               label:'Field 1',
           }
    ],

})
```

I have a function to issue an ajax request that looks something like this:

```
var myDataObject;
var getData= function(callback){ 
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'MY-URL-TO-GET-DATA',
        success: function(response){
            myDataObject= Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText)}})}
```

What I want to do is that after I retrieve my data object, I want to tell the panel to update with the new data.  I'm looking for a call like panel.update(data).

I have seen the update() method on panel, but don't understand how to use it. Do I override it?  It says something about using templates, but I haven't found any good examples.  I'm not even sure if that's the preferred approach for doing this.

I have done similar type things using grid panel and using a data store. In that case I can call refresh() on the data store, but I don't want to use a grid for this particular problem.

Comment: Did you try with doLayout() method of Panel?

Comment: doLayout() would redraw the panel, but not update it with new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `panel.update(data)` but that just injects the text as innerHTML effectively, using the configured `tpl` if necessary.  What are the two text fields in your panel for?  You could set the text of one of those fields to the data, or add a `Ext.form.field.DisplayView` to the panel, and set the value of that to the data.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments below, the answer is to subclass and add a method to do the data refresh.

Comment: I just want the panel to be able to update itself with the data. In this example I only have two fields shown, but in my application I might have many more. I don't want to call Ext.getCmp('myfield').value=myObject.myfield in the getData function, since that is breaking the encapsulation OO principal.

Comment: Where in the panel do you want the data to be displayed?  You could subclass Panel and add a method that takes in the data to display, and then inside that method do `this.getComponent('myfield').setValue(data)` so that you're effectively adding an API to the panel to update that data without breaking encapsulation.

Comment: That's most likely what I want to do. Since I'm new to EXTJS I didn't know if this was the preferred way to do something like this or if there was a better way. Thanks!